# Is it possible to define a variable only once without using final

Tags: java, variables, final

I was wondering if there is a way, in Java, to assign a variable only once. I know there is the final keyword but I would like to achieve same result without having to set the value in the constructor.
I want to set it outside the constructor, because I don't know the value yet.

Comment: You can assign it once by only assigning it once.  ```final``` merely gives you a compile-time error if you violate your own intent.  so, absent any other info as to why you think it necessary, I'd just accept that you don't have the protection. I'd certainly take that approach *in general* before erecting complex machinery for enforcing it. Naturally the field would be marked private.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need check the key before assigning the value, for example:

```
Object key;


public void setValue(Object value) {
    if (key != null) {
        // ignore or throw exception, depending on your business logic
    } else {
        key = value;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way except using the `final`keyword.

You either have to implement a custom setter, which checks, if the value already has been set:

```
public boolean setValue(Object value){
    if( this.value == null){
        this.value = value;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or you use an immutable object, which kind of wraps the above behaviour. There are different libraries, providing immutable objects, or you write one yourself:

```
// Constructor based only allows to set the value when constructing the object
public class Immutable{
    private Object value;

    public Immutable(Object value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}

// Setter based provides a setValue method which checks, if the value is already set or not
public class Immutable{
    private Object value;

    public boolean setValue(Object value){
        if( this.value == null){
            this.value = value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Object getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

When going for a custom Immutable object, you can also use generics to make it more flexible in scope of the type of the value.